# I was creating a php file connecting to a database. Its throwing an error after executing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, mariadb

So I ran a php file where I'm connecting it to a Database and executing a query, but I ended up getting an error stating

> Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT SUM(total)  FROM orders 
>                           WHERE created_at >= ( CURDA' at line 1

but executing these queries will properly result in the query box in SQL as intended.

Here is the php file.

```
<?php

    $username = "examplename";
    $password = "abcdefg";
    $dbname = "exampledb";

    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $fifteenDaysTotal = "SELECT SUM(total)  FROM orders 
                        WHERE created_at >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 15 DAY ) AND orderstatus_id=5
                        ORDER BY created_at DESC";

    $sql = "UPDATE `earnings` SET amount = $fifteenDaysTotal";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }


$conn->close();
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: $fifteenDaysTotal is a sub query or you want result of this to be equal to amount?

Comment: correct statementent `"(SELECT SUM(total)  FROM orders 
                        WHERE created_at >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 15 DAY ) AND orderstatus_id=5
                        ORDER BY created_at DESC) as  tt"

 $sql = "UPDATE earnings SET amount = $fifteenDaysTotal";`

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth I get a result in $fifteenDaysTotal . I am using the result to update the earning table..

Comment: @Gulshan Thank you soo much. Had to correct few things in that. "as tt" was not required. Anyway, post this as answer :)

Comment: @RevanthKumar alias for the select statement. You can ignore it while update. The answer is added below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not storing the result of the query, you are just making that query equal to amount in the $sql query.

Just make the following change:

```
$fifteenDaysTotal_query= "SELECT SUM(total) AS total FROM orders 
WHERE created_at >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 15 DAY ) AND orderstatus_id=5 ORDER BY 
created_at DESC";

$query_total=$conn->query($fifteenDaysTotal_query);
$row_total=$query_total->fetch_assoc();
$fifteenDaysTotal=$row_total['total'];
```

Comment: I am trying this as well. Should it be $fifteenDaysTotal in the last line?

Answer (score 1):

Update as the below statement. This is a `sub query` and we need to `group` this statement.

```
 $fifteenDaysTotal = "(SELECT SUM(total) FROM orders WHERE created_at >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 15 DAY ) AND orderstatus_id=5 ORDER BY created_at DESC)"; 

 $sql = "UPDATE earnings SET amount = $fifteenDaysTotal";
```